# How do you call Square's APIs to Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch, square

**Hello! I'd appreciate any help in making a connection. Here's what I'm trying to 'Get' info from:**

*curl https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations 

-H 'Square-Version: 2022-01-20' 

-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' 

-H 'Content-Type: application/json'*

**Setting the Scopes:**
First I set the following scopes in the manifest file (here's a picture). I followed a similar notation as google's.

[image: App Script manifest for accessing Square api]

**The Apps Script:**

```
function squareLocations() {
  var url = "https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations";
  var headers = {
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "headers": {"Square-Version": "2022-01-20",
                "Authorization": "Bearer <TOKEN>"}
                };
  var data = 
  { 
     'locations':
                {
                'id': locationID,
                'name': locationName,
                'address': locationAdress,
                }
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  var text = response.getResponseCode();
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContextText());
  Logger.log (text);
  Logger.log (json);
  
  
  }
```

response returns a 400 error: invalid scope (lists all scopes).

Comment: In your situation, when you remove the property of `oauthScopes` from `appsscript.json` and test it again, what result will you obtain? Because I thought that your script is the same request as your showing curl command. If the same issue occurs, please create a new Google Apps Script project and copy and paste your script and test it again.

Comment: Please add the scopes as text not as images.

Comment: Questions should not be edited in such way that the answers get invalidated... instead post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

### Background: why the manifest scopes are not relevant to the Square API##

The Square API [uses the Oauth2 protocol](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/overview). The idea of this protocol is as follows: you provide the user an opportunity to log in to their Square account, and in the process, you capture an oauth token that represents that user's login.  This token allows your script to take action on the user's behalf.  The scopes you specify tell the user what types of actions you'll be performing on their behalf, and you are limited to only those actions when calling the API.

The scopes listed in the Apps Script manifest represent the same idea, but for *Google's services*, not any external services like Square.  When you call `ScriptApp.getOauthToken()`, you get a token for performing actions within the *Google account* of the user currently running the Apps Script script.  (The reason you can do this for Google services without presenting a login screen is that the Google user has already logged in in order to run the script in the first place.)

But for any non-Google API like Square, you need to set up a full OAuth2 process, as detailed below:

### The main question: How to access Square's API from Google Apps Script

There is an [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) for Apps Script that handles most of the mechanics of obtaining and storing the token for any API that uses OAuth2.  Start by [adding the library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project) to your script (the library's script id is `1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF`).

Then obtain the callback uri for your project.  Do this by executing the following function from the script editor:

```
function logRedirectUri()
{
  console.log(
    OAuth2.getRedirectUri()
  )
}
```

Now go to the [Square developer dashboard](https://developer.squareup.com/apps), and create a new application.  There's an OAuth link on the left side of the app's main screen.  Go to that link and you'll get the app's Application ID and Application Secret.  You'll need those for your script.  In addition, on this screen you should add the redirect uri you obtained above (when the user logs in to Square, the Square API will now know to redirect to this uri, which your script uses to record the oauth token).

Now you're ready to use the OAuth library to provide the Square sign-in process and then call the API.  I've created a [repo](https://github.com/aaron-dunigan-atlee/gas-square-api) of the code I use for doing this, which you should be able to drop in to your script, but the relevant points are:

1. In the `getSquareService` function, set `SQUARE_CLIENT_ID` and `SQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET` to the id and secret you got from the Square developer dashboard.
2. `getSquareService` is also where you list the [scopes](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/square-permissions) you want for the Square API.

   ```
    function getSquareService()
    {
      var SQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET = '{your square application secret}'
      var SQUARE_CLIENT_ID = '{your square application id}'

      return OAuth2.createService('Square')
        // Set the endpoint URLs.
        .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize')
        .setTokenUrl('https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/token')

        // Set the client ID and secret.
        .setClientId(SQUARE_CLIENT_ID)
        .setClientSecret(SQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET)

        // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
        // complete the OAuth flow.
        .setCallbackFunction('authCallbackSquare')

        // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
        // Change this to .getUserProperties() if you are having multiple google users authorize the service: 
        // this will prevent one user's token from being visible to others.
        .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

        // Set the scopes needed.  For a full list see https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/square-permissions
        .setScope(
          [
            'ORDERS_WRITE',
            'PAYMENTS_WRITE',
            'PAYMENTS_READ',
            'ORDERS_READ',
            'MERCHANT_PROFILE_READ'
          ]
            .join(" ")
        )
        // Set grant type
        .setGrantType('authorization_code')
    }
   ```

And include the callback function that will store the token:

```
function authCallbackSquare(request)
{
  var service = getSquareService();

  // Now process request
  var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (authorized)
  {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else
  {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab.');
  }
}
```

3. If your script is bound to a spreadsheet, you can run `authorizeSquareUser()` in the repo to get a sidebar that initiates the authorization flow.  Otherwise, run this modified version:

   ```
    function authorizeSquareUser()
    {
      var service = getSquareService();
      var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
      console.log("Auth URL is %s", authorizationUrl);
    }
   ```

and then visit the url that is logged. At this url you will log in to your square account, and then you should be redirected to a page that says "Success! You can close this tab."

At this point, the Square user's OAuth token has been stored in the [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties()) of your project.  You are now ready to make a call to the Square API.  When doing this, you access the stored token using `getSquareService().getAccessToken()`, so your headers will look like

```
var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getSquareService().getAccessToken(),
  'Square-Version': '2022-01-20',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Then you can call

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'method': 'GET', 'headers': headers}) // Change GET method depending on the action you are performing
```

Comment: Aaron, thanks for posting. I got very close to the var headers section but ran into an error after running the authorizeSquareUser() function. "Error: Unable to find client by that 'client_id'" Have you ever encountered something like this?

Comment: @Max, Square provides both sandbox and production credentials.   Which are you using in the script?

Comment: Aaron, I tried both Sandbox and Production IDs (separately) - still the same error. Any idea what else it could be?

Comment: @Max, when you're using the sandbox credentials you'll need to use a different url: replace `https://connect.squareup.com` with `https://connect.squareupsandbox.com`.  (The code in the github repo includes conditional logic to handle both.) But the code above should work with your production creds, so I'm not sure what's happening.  Are you getting that error message when you visit the logged authorization URL?  Or when you run one of the functions in the code?

Comment: I reproduced your error by entering an incorrect client id and visiting the auth url.  When you log that auth url, does it look like this? `https://squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=***********&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F...`, where the ******** is exactly the client id assigned to your app in the square dev dashboard, with no additional punctuation or characters?

Comment: Thank you. I'm using production credentials at the moment with the above script. The auth url looks similar to what you have: https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=%7B**********%7D&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.....The %b7b are some additional characters that appear in addition to the client id.

Comment: I tried deleting the"%7B" before and after the client ID and got a new error: Error: Error retrieving token: Not Authorized (line 553, file "Service") - this was with the repo code.

Comment: It sounds like you included the braces `{` and `}` with your id and secret in the code (in a url these are translated as `%7B` and `%7D`).  Take them out--I just included those as placeholders.  Then repeat the whole authorization process and see if that works.

Comment: that did it. I'm at the log in screen. Thanks for your support (invaluable to a new apps scripter).

Comment: Is line needed if I'm using production mode credentials?  var page = template.evaluate().setTitle('Authorize Square').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);

Comment: Yes, that line is still needed (the reference to sandbox mode has nothing to do with the square api)

Comment: Hey there, thank you @AaronDuniganAtLee for this valuable resource! I am trying to use it but am having a bit of trouble. I was accessing square endpoints through a test account and it was working great, then I switched the secret and client ID to my boss's account (which I don't have access to) but it is still giving me data from my test account. I tried resetting the square service with getSquareService().reset();. Any idea what might be going on here? Thank you!

Comment: And how do you use your storeSquareToken() and setSquareUser(merchantId) functions? Would you call them after authorizing the user?

Comment: I'm very confused what is going on here with my previous comment - I do not have access to the account I am attempting to retrieve data from (it is my boss's account). I can see the authorization URL has my boss's client ID and yet the authorization is "successful." Then, it proceeds to give me data from my test account, not from my boss's account, when I hit the endpoints with the token retrieved.

Comment: Additionally, when I try authorizing from a different square account, it doesn't work. It seems like the authorization is using my test account but I am not using the test accounts secret or client ID and I have reset the square service. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I better described the issue I'm having here... https://developer.squareup.com/forums/t/having-problem-with-accessing-different-square-applications-through-their-application-ids-secrets/10449

Comment: @meelszz When you successfully authorize, the access token is stored in Apps Script's User Properties.  This token is used for subsequent API calls.  Changing the client secret and client id has no effect on that until a new authorization is successful.  You'll need to send the auth URL to your boss, have him/her sign in with username/pw, and only then will the access token be updated.

Comment: Gotcha okay. I still seem to be having a problem with accessing the correct application when a user has multiple Square applications attached to their account. No matter which client id/secret I use, when a user logs in, it is always connecting to the first Square application they made, even if the client id/secret belongs to a different Square application of theirs. Any idea why this might be happening? I tried resetting the Square service and am still getting this behavior.

Comment: Also, I want the appscript app to be connected to a specific Square application. i.e. if a user doesn't have access to it, they shouldn't be able to login and it shouldn't just direct to a different application of theirs. Do you know how to change this behavior? Is there something besides the Square service that I need to reset? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the appsscript.json file remove the OAuth scope from square. On this file only include the OAuth scopes required by the Google Apps Script and Advanced Services (like Advanced Sheets Service).

The scopes of APIs called using by `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` might be included when generating the token or on the corresponding API console / App settings (I'm sorry , I don't know the details of Square API).

Comment: Hi, Ruben. Thanks for your comment. I'm getting a new error code now.

Comment: The code included  in [rev 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70981614/3) is completely different as well the error message. Please post a new question.

Comment: Reposted thank you.